# Automorphisms of simple covers of Riemann surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

Can anybody give me a simple proof that simple covers of a Riemann surface have no covering automorphisms?

Comment: What's a simple cover? A one-sheeted covering space?

Comment: it is a cover that has only simple branching, i.e. of type $z \mapsto z^2$

Comment: The example you wrote is a counterexample: $z \mapsto -z$ is a covering automorphism of $z \mapsto z^2$.